# Spring MVC 3.1 : how to map JSON from a PUT request body?

Tags: ajax, json, rest, spring-mvc, mapping

I know this question has been asked a gazillion times, but I still cannot find a solution to my problem, which basically boils down to JSON deserialization from a PUT request.

I've already added HiddenHttpMethodFilter as a filter.

org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-lgpl is in the classpath.

Here is the client part:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/occurrence',
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({id:id,startDate:startDate, endDate:endDate, frequencyType:frequency})
 })
```

Here is the controller part:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/occurrence")
public class OccurrenceController {

    private static final String COMMAND = "eventCommand";

    @Autowired
    private PersistenceCapableOccurrence occurrenceDao;

    @Autowired
    private PersistenceCapableFrequencyType frequencyTypeDao;

    @InitBinder(COMMAND)
    public void customizeConversions(final WebDataBinder binder) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        df.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(df, true));

        EntityConverter<FrequencyType> frequencyTypeEntityConverter = new EntityConverter<FrequencyType>(frequencyTypeDao, FrequencyType.class, "findByValue", String.class);
        ((GenericConversionService) binder.getConversionService()).addConverter(frequencyTypeEntityConverter);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = PUT, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Long saveOccurrence(@RequestBody Occurrence occurrence) {
        return occurrenceDao.saveOrUpdate(occurrence);
    }
}
```

Here are my two domain classes (Occurrence and FrequencyType):

```
public class Occurrence {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime startDate;
    @Column(name="end_date")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime endDate;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "frequency_type", nullable = false)
    private FrequencyType frequencyType;

     /* C-tor (1 with [start,end,freq], another with [start,freq]), getters (no setters) */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "frequency_types")
public class FrequencyType {

    public enum FrequencyTypeValues {
        ONCE, DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY, YEARLY;
    }

    private String value;

    public FrequencyType() {}
    public FrequencyType(FrequencyTypeValues value) {
        this.value = value.name();
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        //validates value against the enumerated/allowed values (ie throws exceptions if invalid value)
        FrequencyTypeValues.valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

All I get at the end is a 400 response.
Example :

```
PUT Request
{"id":"","startDate":"20/10/2012 17:32","endDate":"","frequencyType":"YEARLY"}

Response
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:9999/occurrence"
```

Thanks in advance for your help !
Rolf

Comment: Are you sure your http://localhost:9999/occurence is a valid endpoint, does it work directly from a browser, what you are seeing could be a response from your servlet container rather from Spring

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure it is, my DispatcherServlet is mapped to /.